# Applyingv a 2D mask onto a 3D rgb color list

Tags: pandas, numpy, image-recognition, image-preprocessing, image-segmentation

#### Problem

I have the following image data as a 3D numpy array containing rgb values of the image in a **(n,n,3) shaped list (Image)**. I also have data of the corresponding black and white mask image in a **(n,n) list (Mask)**.
The goal is to apply the Mask on the Image data, so that only rgb values corresponding to white mask areas are shown.

```
Image: (n,n,3)
 - Shape: (200,200,3)
 - Size:  120000
```

```
Mask: (n,n)
 - shape:(200,200)
 - size: 40000
```

My Idea was to broadcast/apply the mask on the image.. something like this:

```
                                         [ (n, n, 1)     
Image ~ Mask =  (n, n, 3) * (n, n)   =     (n, n, 1)     *   [(n,n,1)]
                                           (n, n, 1) ]
```

#### Implementation

Mask data is represented as list of 0 and 255 values:

```
Mask

 - shape:  (200,200)
 - size:   40000
 - Values: [0, 0, 0] = black, [255, 255, 255] = white

array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

The Image data is represented as list of rgb values:

```
Image

 - Shape: (200,200,3)
 - Size:  120000 

array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       ...,

       [[189, 240, 247],
        [227, 242, 242],
        [207, 206, 207],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[202, 254, 254],
        [242, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[163, 242, 255],
        [161, 254, 255],
        [213, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Code to apply apply the mask:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma


def apply_mask(
    array: List[str],  # Dict[str, np.ndarray],
    mask: List[str]  # Dict[str, np.ndarray]
):
    """
    Applies a list of boolean values (mask) to an array using indexing. This will return only
    the elements that satisfy a condition, where the mask contains 'True' or 1. 

    Libraries
    --------- 
    numpy as np
    numpy.ma as ma

    Parameters
    ----------
    array : List[str]
        The Array
    mask: List[str]
        The Mask

    Returns
    -------
    masked_arr : List[str]
        Filtered Array

    Ex.
    If you want to apply this mask = [[0,0,0,]
                                      [0,1,1]                                           
                                      [1,1,1]]                                        

    on this array; arr = [[0,1,2], you would use: 
                          [3,4,5],
                          [6,7,8]]

    apply_mask(arr,mask) = [[-- -- --]
                            [-- 4 5] 
                            [6 7 8]]
    """
    masked_arr = ma.masked_array(array, np.logical_not(mask))
    return masked_arr
```

Code to test it using the unit matrix:

```py
def test_mask():
    # Test with arr, mask below
    
    x = np.arange(120000)
    arr = np.reshape(x, (200, 200, 3))
    mask = np.identity(200)
    return print(apply_mask(arr, mask))
```

#### Question

In order to use this approach I would need to reshape arr to 3x (200,200,1) and mask to (200,200,1) and then apply the mask on all 3 arrays.
How do I do that?
Some of my ideas where as follows:

```py
 -  new_arr = arr.reshape(-1), then use then use the 1D somehow
 -  new_mask = np.atleast_3d(mask).shape 
 -  new_arr = np.array_split(arr,3)
```